# Variables set in a bash 'while read' loop are unset after it

Tags: linux, bash

I try the code below to store the command output in an array
but the array elements cannot be printed after the "while loop"
I mean in the last line of my code
is there any problem in my code?

```
#! /bin/bash

ls -a | while read line

do
    array[$i]="$line "  

        echo ${array[ $i ]}
        ((i++))
done

echo ${array[@]}  <------------
```

Comment: What do you mean by _the array elements cannot be printed after the "while loop"_?  You got an error?  No error, but nothing got printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you add the elements in a *sub*shell.  To elaborate:

```
command1 | command2
```

causes `command2` to be executed in a subshell, which is a separate execution environment.  This implies that the variables set in `command2` are not available to the *current* shell, whose execution environment is not affected.  You could instead use process substitution to achieve the same:

```
while read line; do
 ...
done < <(ls -l)
```

Please note that [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is not recommended; try using `find` instead.

Comment: thanks a lot, i work for me. actually, i don't know it will work seperately

Comment: Good answer; for the sake of completeness: `command1` is _also_ executed in a subshell.

Comment: But Process Substitution is only working with `bash` and not `sh` (POSIX), unfortunately.